# N distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that a linear transformation on an n-dimensional vector space has at most n distinct eigenvalues?

It can't be more than the max number of eigenvectors (or "eigenvector spaces" or something because if $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector then so are all $a \mathbf v$).  So maybe that limits it --- except that the identity transformation has every vector as an eigenvector, so maybe that's not the right way to go about it.  Any hints?

Comment: Do you know about the relationship between the eigenvalues and the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: The characteristic equation is $\det(\lambda I - A)=0$.  $I$ has n entries.  Thus the polynomial in $\lambda$ one gets from $\det(\lambda I - A)=0$ will have as it's highest term $[(\lambda - a_{11})(\lambda-a_{22}) \cdots (\lambda -a_{nn})] -$ something $= \lambda^n -$ something else.  Thus by the fundamental theorem of algebra, there can be at most n distinct $\lambda$s.  $\square$  That's not exactly rigorous, but is that what you were getting at?

Comment: It's entirely rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

**Proof-hint without use of characteristic polynomial**

If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r$ are $r$ distinct eigenvalues and $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ are eigenvectors associated to these eigenvalues respectively then they are linearly independent. The proof is done by induction:

$$a_1 x_1+\cdots a_rx_r=0\tag1$$
and apply to $(1)$ the linear transformation $T$ we get
$$a_1\lambda_1 x_1+\cdots+a_r\lambda_r x_r=0\tag2$$
so $(2)-\lambda_r(1)$ gives a linear combination of $r-1$ eigenvectors with distinct eiegenvalues and we apply the induction hpothesis. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So the base step is $\lambda_2 (a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2) -(a_1 \lambda_1 x_1 + a_2 \lambda_2 x_2)=0 \Rightarrow a_1(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1) x_1 = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 = 0 \Rightarrow a_2=0 \Rightarrow \{x_1, x_2\}$ are linearly independent, I guess.  I don't quite get how this is induction.  Isn't the inductive step supposed to have $r+1$ instead of $r-1$?

Comment: We assume the result true for all $r-1$ distinct eigenvalues and we prove it for $r$ distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: So in the base step I wrote above, it actually should be prefaced by something like: "Assume $x_1$ & $x_2$ are eigenvectors and thus linearly independent (with themselves) because eigenvectors can't be $0$".  Then we've proved that two eigenvectors form a linearly independent set.  Then, from your proof, $r-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors implies there are $r$ linearly independent eigenvectors (as long as $r \leq n$).

Comment: Yes exact and notice that we can even take one vector in the base step.

Comment: Nicely argued +

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A set of eigenvectors, each with a different eigenvalue, is linearly independent.

Comment: OK.  So linear transformations are functions (and thus single-valued), thus the number of distinct eigenvalues can't be greater than the number of eigenvector spaces.  A set of eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues is linearly independent.  There can be at most n linearly independent vectors in an n-D space, thus there can be at most n distinct eigenvalues. $\square$    Does that work?

Comment: Yes, but do you also see how to prove that they _are_ linearly independent?